# Form submitting on return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form id="sizeForm" style="float:right;">
  <input value="test" name="comments" type="text">
  <input class="btn-sm btn-main" value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

Which I'm trying to submit using ajax but the form is posting, here's the JQuery:

```
$("#sizeForm").submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax/actions/editSize.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (dataBack) {
                  $('#size2'+dataBack).fadeOut().promise().done(
                    function(){
                      $('#size1'+dataBack).fadeIn(); 
                    }
                  );
                 }
              });
              return false;
      });
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I thhink you have to do something like : $("#sizeForm").submit(function (event) {
`event.preventDefault();...`

Comment: Have you tried preventing the default before the `$.ajax()` -> `$("#sizeForm").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax({...})`?

Comment: I just created a JSFiddle with your code and it is working, so perhaps something else is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/0rhjo3hh/ Are there any errors on the JS console?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your PHP script (which you haven't provided), but here are some ideas.

HTML:

```
<form id="sizeForm" style="float:right;">
  <input value="test" name="comments" type="text">
  <input class="btn-sm btn-main" value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#sizeForm").on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/actions/editSize.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (dataBack) {
            $('#size2'+dataBack).fadeOut().promise().done(
                function(){
                $('#size1'+dataBack).fadeIn(); 
                }
            );
         }
    });
    return false;
});
```

In your PHP script add something like this so you know the value is received. This will show in the network tab in the browser developer tools.

```
if (!empty($_POST['comments'])) {
    echo "form submitted!";
    exit;
}
```

In the network tab, you should see an entry like `POST editSize.php`. If you don't see it, the form was not sent. If you do see it, open it up and look at the "post" tab. This will show you what was sent. Then, your "response" tab will show you the output from your PHP script.